# Can't link backend to frontend on Kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, go, kubernetes, networking

I have an app with a Go backend (linked to a psql db) and a React frontend that I try to deploy on k8s. from the side of my backend, everything is working but when I deploy my frontend deployment and service, I **can** access with a port forward 3000:3000 but its not linked to my backend and when I use the port forward 3000:80 its not working.

This is my main.go, my App.js and my deployments for backend and frontend

```
function App() {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);

  const fetchLinks = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}`);
      setLinks(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: kamloic/tl-frontend:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
            value: http://backend-service:8080/links
```

this is what I have for the port forward 3000:80

```
 kubectl port-forward frontend-deployment-75fb894884-lh7cn 3000:80

Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3000 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:3000 -> 80
Handling connection for 3000
E0805 01:54:07.777540   71245 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 3000 -> 80: error forwarding port 80 to pod ae2473b920409007d7cd4ecef2cc14184deecf926a425dc36dcc74b3acb9f4f1, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-06abb28d-2d14-8a28-e682-7f9609fd04a7": failed to connect to localhost:80 inside namespace "ae2473b920409007d7cd4ecef2cc14184deecf926a425dc36dcc74b3acb9f4f1", IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found
E0805 01:54:07.781703   71245 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod
```

also when I do a `curl EXTERNAL_IP/links` or a `curl EXTERNAL_IP` (EXTERNAL_IP being the external IP provided by my service) I have the index.html of the Js project (for both curls)

Comment: I'm guessing the React application is running in the end user's browser; even if you have a container that's serving the code, the Javascript engine that actually runs it is outside the cluster.  That means it can't see `ClusterIP` type services and other things that only exist inside the cluster.  I'd create [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) objects for the two parts of the system, at which point you should be able to use a path-only URL to reach the backend from the frontend.